# how to find out index-name and it's definition using query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I'm using `PostgreSQL`, In my database I've 75 `indexes` are there,is there any way to figure out all the index and its definition associated with the `tables` ?

Note : Yes, I can see it via `pgAdmin` but i need a `select` query for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

am assuming that your *schema* is `public`

```
SELECT 
   tablename,indexname,indexdef  
FROM 
  pg_catalog.pg_indexes 
WHERE
 schemaname = 'public' -- <- give your schema name here  
ORDER BY by tablename
```